# Flood filling of 3-dimensional polygon

Tags: c++, math, polygon, computational-geometry, flood-fill

here is a problem for you ;)

I have a 3-dimensional array filled with 1s and 0s. The 1s represent 3 dimensional complex polygons ( not simple polygons ). Only the boundaries of the polygons have the value 1, the inside is filled with 0s. Now here is the problem:

I need a fast algorithm to flood-fill these polygons with 1s. The arrays usually have a dimension of approx. 512x512x100.

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example in 2d:

0000111110000
0000100010000
0000100010000
0000111110000

should result in

0000111110000
0000111110000
0000111110000
0000111110000

---

is this the correct 3 dimensional solution for @Mikolas algorithm?

```
    void scan_polygon(int frames, int rows, int cols, char data[][][], char result[][][]){
for(int f=0; f < frames; ++f)
for(int r=0; r<rows; ++r)
for(int s = 0, c=0; c<cols-1; ++c)
{
    s ^= s ? ( data[f][r][c] && !data[f][r][c+1]) :
             (!data[f][r][c] &&  data[f][r][c-1]);

    result[f][r][c] = s;
}

for(int f=0; f < frames; ++f)
for(int c=0; c<cols; ++c)
for(int s = 0, r=0; r<rows-1; ++r)
{
    s ^= s ? ( data[f][r][c] && !data[f][r+1][c]) :
             (!data[f][r][c] &&  data[f][r-1][c]);

    result[f][r][c] &= s;
}
```

}

Best regards,

stef

Comment: when you say "flood-fill", do you mean to initialize the entire array to the value `1`?  Or you just want a fast way to set the boundary points to `1`, and the rest of the array to `0`?

Comment: Does each array represent one polygon?

Comment: I agree with @6502; a complex polygon in 3-space doesn't even **have** a well-defined "inside!" If you post an example of a small array and the desired output, we'll have a lot better chance of helping you. -1 until then.

Comment: I think he means a polyhedron, not polygon. IIUC the interior of the FACES is all ones but the polyhedron is "empty"

Comment: Whoa, you guys are fast. Thanks so far!

Comment: one array can contain multiple polygons.

Comment: Removed my -1 because 6502 correctly interpreted the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single for loop, if you assume that your polygon is manifold.  Just start at the upper left corner, and keep track of the parity as you cross an edge.

A simple 2D version (with transpose case added in):

```
void scan_polygon(int rows, int cols, char** data, char** result)
{
    for(int r=0; r<rows; ++r)
    for(int s = 0, c=0; c<cols-1; ++c)
    {
        s ^= s ? ( data[r][c] && !data[r][c+1]) :
                 (!data[r][c] &&  data[r][c-1]);

        result[r][c] = s;
    }


    for(int c=0; c<cols; ++c)
    for(int s = 0, r=0; r<rows-1; ++r)
    {
        s ^= s ? ( data[r][c] && !data[r+1][c]) :
                 (!data[r][c] &&  data[r-1][c]);

        result[r][c] &= s;
    }
}
```

Where this can break down is if you have a dangling pixel or edge poking out along a scan line, for example:

```
00000000000000000000        
00000000*11111111111   <--- Whoops!
000000*111*000000000
00000*11111*00000000
```

To fix this, you can just repeat the process on a transposed array, then AND all the results together.  A similar approach has been used by Sud et al to voxelize meshes on the GPU.  It isn't flawless, since you can have configurations of multiple non-manifold vertices where the noisy cones from them intersect, but if you can guarantee that won't happen (or else if it only happens rarely), it is one of the simplest methods that I know of to get a quick result.

EDIT: Modified solution to show how to AND the arrays back together after doing the iteration.

Comment: Excellent! This should work in 3D as well, although the OP will have to figure out what is meant by "transpose ... AND" in that context.

Comment: Yes, this really looks like a good solution. And Chris is right, could you please explain what you mean with " ANDing with a transposed array". Thanks so far, you are great!

Comment: @stef: Sure thing, I just updated the solution.  In 3D, you would want to do this for each of the 3 axes.

Comment: @stef Since you're going to need to understand what is going on to implement this in 3D, let me elaborate a little bit: when you run it starting from the "upper left corner" on Mikola's example data, one of your rows will have a `00000000*11111111111` in it. If you run if from the "lower right corner" instead, you will get `11111111*00000000000` instead. Since they disagree, actually the whole thing should be 0s. You will need to experiment with some sample polyhedra having jaggy edges to figure out exactly how to implement this in 3D.

Comment: Also note that even if you do the traversal over each axis, this technique can still fail in the presence of non-manifold points.  The only way to reliably fix these problems is to filter your data to remove these corners, or else modify the scanline process to skip over them.

Comment: @Mikola, would you mind posting the 3-dimensional solution? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it true that for all `s`, `s ^= s == 0`?

Comment: @James Brock:  That's a ternary operator there.  It just checks if it croses a boundary in the data.

Comment: AND only means multiply... 1x1=1 1x0=0 ... transpose means scan it on x, y, z axes and even in obliques.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a standard floodfill approach could be used in this case:

```
active_cells = [seed]
while active_cells:
    new_active_cells = []
    for cell in active_cells:
        for nh in neighbor(cell):
            if not filled(nh):
                fill(nh)
                new_active_cells.append(nh)
    active_cells = new_active_cells
```

if you are not sure that the interior or the exterior are connected (and therefore it's not possible to find a single "seed") then what you can do is iterating over all cells, and once you find a cell with a zero then you can call the above floodfill code to compute the connected component. Repeating it for other cells found to be zero you will end up with all the connected regions that the faces are partitioning the space in.

Of course for the above code to be working it's required that the faces are tight in respect to the chosen connectivity.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but won't this fill things just to the outside of the boundary as well as things inside it?

Comment: If the seed is inside and the boundary is thight (depending on the definition of connectivity used) then the paint won't be able to escape the polyhedron. Note that this assumes a polyhedron with solid FACES not just the edges. Like I said before with just edges the problem is not well posed.

Comment: Oh! I missed completely what you were doing here, starting with a seed. Since this is a complex region though and might have more than one "inside" bit, he will need to actually fill the **outside** first with 2s or something since I think the outside is guaranteed to be a connected region, then replace all the remaining 0s with 1s. +1 by the way. :P

Comment: Depending on the topology indeed not even the "exterior" is surely connected. Consider for example one sphere inside another sphere...